# D3.js how to get value from previous d?

Tags: d3.js, bar-chart

I'm making a [stacked bar-charts](http://bl.ocks.org/anupsavvy/9513382)

The example code is too hard to understand so I'm figuring it out on my own.
There's a `g` for each stack, in which there're some `rect`, they are stacked.

So I could offset the `y` attribute since the second `rect` in the same stack, so as to put it "on top" of the previous `rect`.
The problem is, how could I get all the previous `d` as the offset?

```
var offset = 0
  var rectsEnter = rects
  .enter()
  .append('rect')
  .attr('y', function(d){
    //offset won't work b/c this is not a loop
    return h - d - offset
  })
  .attr('height', function(d){
    offset += d
    return d
  })
```

Is there a way to get previous `d`?
Or is there a better way to do this stacked bar?

Thanks.

Comment: The callback function of attr receives a second argument, i, that represents the index of d in the collection. You could use collection[i-1] to retrieve the previous element.

Comment: There is absolutely no need to do what you are asking: the stack layout takes care of that for you.